# mysql5.7 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax will update extra column

Tags: mysql, go

mysql5.7  'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' syntax will update extra column even if you haven't updated

use 'insert ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...' to update some_data = VALUES(some_data), it also update created_at column

```
result, err := DB.Exec("INSERT INTO `test_duplicate_key_bug_table`(some_data,created_at) VALUES(?,?)", "test data", createdAt)
    require.NoError(t, err)
    id, err := result.LastInsertId()
    require.NoError(t, err)
    // mysql's timestamp only storage second's level date, re-find it's real datetime
    row := DB.QueryRow("SELECT created_at FROM `test_duplicate_key_bug_table` WHERE id=? LIMIT 1", id)
    var oldCreatedAt time.Time
    err = row.Scan(&oldCreatedAt)
    require.NoError(t, err)

    result, err = DB.Exec("INSERT INTO `test_duplicate_key_bug_table`(id,some_data,created_at) VALUES(?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE some_data = VALUES(some_data)", id, "test data again", time.Now())
    require.NoError(t, err)

    row = DB.QueryRow("SELECT some_data,created_at FROM `test_duplicate_key_bug_table` WHERE id=? LIMIT 1", id)
    var newCreatedAt time.Time
    var newData string
    err = row.Scan(&newData, &newCreatedAt)
    require.NoError(t, err)

    fmt.Printf("old time %s \n", oldCreatedAt)
    fmt.Printf("new time %s \n", newCreatedAt)
    fmt.Printf("new data %s \n", newData)
```

output:

```
old time 2019-04-12 03:29:17 +0000 UTC 
new time 2019-04-12 03:29:27 +0000 UTC 
new data test data again
```

but only update id = VALUES(id), it work well

```
result, err := DB.Exec("INSERT INTO `test_duplicate_key_bug_table`(some_data,created_at) VALUES(?,?)", "test data", createdAt)
    require.NoError(t, err)
    id, err := result.LastInsertId()
    require.NoError(t, err)
    // mysql's timestamp only storage second's level date, re-find it's real datetime
    row := DB.QueryRow("SELECT created_at FROM `test_duplicate_key_bug_table` WHERE id=? LIMIT 1", id)
    var oldCreatedAt time.Time
    err = row.Scan(&oldCreatedAt)
    require.NoError(t, err)

    result, err = DB.Exec("INSERT INTO `test_duplicate_key_bug_table`(id,some_data,created_at) VALUES(?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = VALUES(id) ", id, "test data again", time.Now())
    require.NoError(t, err)

    row = DB.QueryRow("SELECT some_data,created_at FROM `test_duplicate_key_bug_table` WHERE id=? LIMIT 1", id)
    var newCreatedAt time.Time
    var newData string
    err = row.Scan(&newData, &newCreatedAt)
    require.NoError(t, err)

    fmt.Printf("old time %s \n", oldCreatedAt)
    fmt.Printf("new time %s \n", newCreatedAt)
    fmt.Printf("new data %s \n", newData)
```

output:

```
old time 2019-04-12 03:29:17 +0000 UTC 
new time 2019-04-12 03:29:17 +0000 UTC 
new data test data
```

I am using [docker's mysql](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/bb7ea52db4e12d3fb526450d22382d5cd8cd41ca/5.7/Dockerfile)

[full example code](https://gist.github.com/xiachengjia/23004e2047168bfc243ee4f4c03025d3)

I guess it's the "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" driver problem

Comment: Please add your table definition (the output of `show create table test_duplicate_key_bug_table`). Possible reasons for this behaviour in order of probability: a) your `created_at` column is defined with `on update current_timestamp` (which is expected to behave exactly as you describe if `id` is the primary key) b) you enabled `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` in your configuration c) you have an `on update` trigger on your table that sets that column d-y) aliens z) a bug in the driver.

Comment: @Solarflare yes, the created_at column has ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attribute, thanks